# How to set value of dropdown list with a gridview boundfield

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to set the value of ListItem Yes to PointsPossible datafield. Any insight would help. Thanks!

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CellPadding="10">
         <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Question" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="Question" />
              <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOpt1" runat="server" ShowHeader="False" AutoPostBack="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOpt_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="???">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="PointsPossible" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Points Possible" ShowHeader="True" SortExpression="PointsPossible"  />
         </Columns>           
 </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different ways of doing this that I can think of:

1. Handle the `OnRowDataBound` event of the gridview and do the data bindings for the drop down list inside this event. [Here's](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-populate-DropDownList-in-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx) a step-by-step article
2. Add an additional `SqlDataSource` for the drop down list and set the the `DataSourceID` of the drop down list to the `SqlDataSource`. [Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178294(v=vs.100).aspx) a step-by-step article

[image: Binding to drop down list inside gridview asp.net]

Comment: This helped me find what I was looking for. I was wanting to change the ValueField of just 1 of the drop down list items and the example above changed the TextField as well. I have posted my solution below. Thank you for your insight and leading me to the solution @Denis Wessels

Comment: Please upvote and mark as answered for those solution that help you

Comment: My rep is too low to upvote but I got you on the answered part. Didn't realize I could do that without higher rep.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I currently have working

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var ddl = e.Row.FindControl("ddlOpt") as DropDownList;
            string val = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;

            if (ddl != null)
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                list.Add("", "");
                list.Add("0", "No");
                list.Add(val, "Yes");

                ddl.DataSource = list;
                ddl.DataTextField = "Value";
                ddl.DataValueField = "Key";
                ddl.DataBind();

            }
        }
    }
```